# Identifying what item have been deleted (created and modifed) in a Formik FieldArray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Was wondering if Formik has a native solution for identifying the addition and deletion (and update) of `FieldArray` in the form ?

I have the code on sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/jn7x2m75o9  ( based on the original Formik Array example @ https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/examples/Arrays.js )

but also the relevant part here :

With an Initial `state` of **3 friend** defined,  how can I know in my `onSubmithandler` which one were **modified,deleted,updated**.

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from "formik";

const initialValues = {
  friends: [
    {
      name: "Friend_A",
      email: "email_A@somewhere.com"
    },
    {
      name: "Friend_B",
      email: "email_B@somewhere.com"
    },
    {
      name: "Friend_C",
      email: "email_C@somewhere.com"
    }
  ]
};

const mySubmit = values => console.log();

const SignIn = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Invite friends</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={values => {
        var itemRemoved = values.GetItemRemoveFromArray; // This is what I'm looking for
        console.log(itemRemoved);
        // Would print Friend_A

        var itemAdded = values.GetItemAddedFromArray; // This is what I'm looking for
        console.log(itemAdded);
        // Would print New_Friend

        var itemUpdated = values.GetItemUpdatedInArray; // This is what I'm looking for
        console.log(itemUpdated);
        // Would print Friend_C

        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500);
      }}
      render={({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name="friends"
            render={({ insert, remove, push }) => (
              <div>
                {values.friends.length > 0 &&
                  values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                    <div className="row" key={index}>
                      <div className="col">
                        <label htmlFor={`friends.${index}.name`}>Name</label>
                        <Field
                          name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                          placeholder="Jane Doe"
                          type="text"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                          component="div"
                          className="field-error"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col">
                        <label htmlFor={`friends.${index}.email`}>Email</label>
                        <Field
                          name={`friends.${index}.email`}
                          placeholder="jane@acme.com"
                          type="email"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage
                          name={`friends.${index}.name`}
                          component="div"
                          className="field-error"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col">
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="secondary"
                          onClick={() => remove(index)}
                        >
                          X
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="secondary"
                  onClick={() => push({ name: "", email: "" })}
                >
                  Add Friend
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          />
          <button type="submit">Invite</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);

export default SignIn;
```

So if with the above a user where to :

1. Click on the X below Friend_A
2. Modify Friend_C email to email_C@nothere.com
3. Click "Add Friend"
4. Enter value Name: New_Friend_X and email: XX@YY.com
5. Click "Add Friend"
6. Enter value Name: New_Friend_Z and email: Friend_Z@coolplace.com
7. Click "X" button below newly entered "New_Friend_X"
8. Click "Invite"

in my mySubmit I'm looking for a way to easily get :

1. Friend_A was Removed
2. Friend_C was Modified
3. New_Friend_Z was added (was not in the original initialValues to formik)

(I Don't care about New_Friend_X. No need to know it was added/removed )

Point of this is to minimize rest call to the back end to create/update entity/link and also I really dont want to write my own "secondary state" in the `onClick` handler of the remove button before calling the `remove(index)` handler provided by **Formik** to track what need to be deleted from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Its not built into Formik, but it is not hard to do in javascript.

First, understand that Formik *clones* the object you give to `initialValues`. So in `onSubmit`, you will compare the final value to your original object.

The incoming data:

```
const initialFriends = [
  {
    name: "Friend_A",
    email: "email_A@somewhere.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Friend_B",
    email: "email_B@somewhere.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Friend_C",
    email: "email_C@somewhere.com"
  }
];

const initialValues = { friends: initialFriends };
```

Modified Formik declaration:

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues}
  ...
  onSubmit={values => {
    const { added, deleted, changed } = addDeleteChange(
      initialFriends,
      values.friends
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(
        "Added: " + JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(added.entries()))
      );
      alert(
        "Deleted: " + JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(deleted.entries()))
      );
      alert(
        "Changed:" + JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(changed.entries()))
      );
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }, 500);
  }}
  ...
```

Helper functions:

```
function partition(array, filter) {
  let pass = [],
    fail = [];
  array.forEach(e => (filter(e) ? pass : fail).push(e));
  return [pass, fail];
}

const addDeleteChange = (in1, out1) => {
  let inMap = new Map(in1.map(f => [f.name, f]));
  let outMap = new Map(out1.map(f => [f.name, f]));
  let inNames = new Set(inMap.keys());
  let outNames = new Set(outMap.keys());
  let [kept, added] = partition(out1, f => inNames.has(f.name));
  let deleted = in1.filter(f => !outNames.has(f.name));
  //alert(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(deleted.entries())));
  let changed = kept.filter(f => f.email !== inMap.get(f.name).email);
  //alert(JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(changed.entries())));
  return { added: added, deleted: deleted, changed: changed };
};
```

[Code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formikanswertrackaddremove-um83j)

---

NOTE: If you change the *name* of a friend, that will appear as a *delete* of original friend and an *add* of a new friend.
A more robust solution would be to add a (hidden) "id" field to each friend. Then instead of comparing *name*, would compare *id*.
That requires generating a new id as add each friend.